# disable a checkbox in gridview at server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want to disable a checkbox present in a gridview at server side...So that once it is checked it is disabled at server side  and is never enabled again...Can you help..

```
    <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild" runat="server"  AutoPostBack= "true" CommandArgument= '<%# Eval("id") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </asp:Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Checkbox changed event and from there you need to set `Enabled=false` for every check

```
protected void chkchild_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    int index = row.RowIndex;
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)Gridview.Rows[index].FindControl("chkchild");
     if(cb1.Checked)
     {
        cb1.Enabled ='false';
     }

}
```

Comment: It's working for one time only.What I want is once it's disabled after check it is in same state  and is never enabled.

Comment: @kritiupadhyay then that state need to be stored in the DB with a  seperate column , again while binding the gridview in `onRowDataBound` you can set the Checkbox to disabled mode, `Or`  you need to tell some flag which checkbox need to be disabled.. are you having any specific column , explaining this criteria

Comment: No..I am not having any column that is storing checkbox values

Comment: @kritiupadhyay then you need to specify which rows need to be in disabled mode because  Browser is a stateless

Comment: Actually this is just a random selection of rows using checkbox..So what concept should I use in an order to disable it ..

Comment: @kritiupadhyay it is other way around , what is the reason to disable it , then we will get a logic to permanently disable it

Comment: Actually it's user to user selection...Once a specific user select a record in gridview that row should not be allowed to be selected by other users....So,checkbox should become disable permanently..

Comment: @kritiupadhyay got it , so based on userId, there will be Unique ID for each row of the gridview right ? and also do u have access for database designing?

Comment: Yes u got it right...Every user has a unique id..Yes.I do have access to database designing as well

Comment: @kritiupadhyay so add a New Column in the DB designing and By default keep that column as `Isdisable =false`  on checking a particular checkbox in the gridview , update that column with the `true` , so when ever you are binding the data check with this flag, if it is `false` allow user for selecting .